# Infinite main loop in F#

Tags: design-patterns, f#, functional-programming

A usual pattern for CLI application is to run in infinite loop, until user types some quit command. Like, in C language:

```
while(1){
scanf("%c", &op);
    ...
    else if(op == "q")
        break;
    }
```

What would be the pattern for such console application in F# (tried to use tail recursrion, but failed)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typing in browser, thus may contain errors:

```
let rec main() = 
    let c = System.Console.ReadKey()
    if c.Key = System.ConsoleKey.Q then () // TODO: cleanup and exit
    else 
    // TODO: do something in main
    main()
```

Comment: will this overflow the stack if tail recursion isn't on?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a none blocking version that responds to single key press.

```
open System

let rec main() = 
    // run code here

    // you may want to sleep to prevent 100% CPU usage
    // Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

    if Console.KeyAvailable then
        match Console.ReadKey().Key with
        | ConsoleKey.Q -> ()
        | _ -> main()
    else
        main()

main()
```

Comment: May want a `Sleep(0)` or `SwitchToThread()` in the `else` or that will be a high CPU usage loop. :-]

Comment: Wouldn't this eventually cause a stack overflow?

Comment: @nphx F# supports tail recursion.  This allows recursive code to be written in F# that won't overflow and is just as fast as looped version.  Try searching for "F# tail recursion".

Comment: @gradbot Being new to the functional world I was not aware of that concept. Cool.

Answer (score 6):

Such a function can be useful:

```
let rec forever f = 
  f()
  forever f
```

Usage:

```
forever <| fun () ->
  //function body
```

A more literal translation of your code, however, would be:

```
while true do
  //body
```

Comment: Lovely syntax but not very practical when you want an exit condition I would say.

Answer (score 4):

Also

```
while true do
    (* ..code.. *)
```

But I guess tail-recursion is more fancy (they'll both compile to the same thing under `--optimize`).